# Flush Partial Response In Snap

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I want something like this

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import           Control.Concurrent     (threadDelay)
import           Control.Monad.IO.Class
import           Snap.Core
import           Snap.Http.Server

main :: IO ()
main = quickHttpServe site

site :: Snap ()
site = do
        writeBS "testing\n"
        liftIO $ threadDelay (1000 * 1000 * 5)
        writeBS "one two three"
```

Except that I want to flush the response right after writing `testing\n`. Should be simple but my googling skills are failing me.

Comment: I think you'll need to drop down to `Snap.Iteratee` and `enumerator` using `Snap.Core`'s `addToOutput`. The `write*` functions buffer everything in blaze-builders.

Comment: I think so too but hasn't snap dropped iteratees and use io-streams? I can't find any docs for the new streaming api unfortunately.